# Javascript, get the autoId from a Firebase child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to find the autoID which was auto generated by firebase during the save.

my firebase structure is :

```
-flights
    -userID
        -autoID-1
            -info1
            -info2
            -info3
        -autoID-2
            -info4
            -info5
            -info6
        -autoID-3
            -info7
            -info8
            -info9
        -autoID-4
            -info10
            -info11
            -info12
```

My objectif is to get all the userID informations in a HTML table.

I think I need to read the informations from firebase into a javascript array and then add a new html table line for each new entry in my JS array.

The HTML structure that I want is :

```
line 1 : INFO 1 / INFO 2 / INFO 3
line 2 : INFO 4 / INFO 5 / INFO 6 
line 3 : INFO 7 / INFO 8 / INFO 9
line 4 : INFO 10 / INFO 11 / INFO 12 
...
```

But I totally don't know How to get the informations from firebase with javascript when I use autoID...

for now I try this JS code :

```
return firebase.database().ref('/flights/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            var flightKey = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().autoID) || 'NULL';
            alert(flightKey);
        });
```

but nothing happens ....

How can I fix it ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple flights for a user, you need to loop over those with `Snapshot.forEach()`. So something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('/flights/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(flightSnapshot) {
    var flightKey = flightSnapshot.key;
    alert(flightKey);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand the need to loop the function, I try this code, I switch the alert for `console.log(flightKey);`but nothing appear ... maybe the code didn't find something ?

Comment: OHHHH my mistake in fact my `userId` is bad formatted .... this work when I put the right sentence `userID` my bad ...